# When replacing carpet, can you re-use the tackless strips?

Tags: carpet

I need to replace some carpet. Thee carpet was installed over a concrete slab, so the tackless strips were fastened down with concrete nails. The tackless strips seem to be in decent enough condition. Do I have to replace them? This would be more of a hassle then it would be if I was dealing with a wood subfloor due to the necessity of sinking new nails into a 40 year-old slab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly, if they're in "decent enough condition". Which means they aren't showing any signs of mold and are still well fastened. And that the 'tacks' will still grab the new carpet properly (I've never seen any so mangled that this was a problem).

Personal advice: whatever reason you took the old carpet out, will be the same reason you'll have to again. -*You like oak, Jimmy?* I'm a tile guy myself...

Comment: Haha! Well, the old stuff is really bad office building carpet with practically no pad, and this is for a kid's bedroom.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly you can and you should! If these look usable to your eye then use them!

If you want an alternative to carpet think about vinyl. This material comes in so many styles and colors now from a wood look to stone or tile. And it will out last your kids as well!